# get single data from local json with id

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

> **I'm building list app with ionic 4 .all item list view work from local**
>   **json ,  but single item with id not get from local json**

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule' },
  { path: 'details/:id', loadChildren: './details/details.module#DetailsPageModule' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**home.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { RecipiService } from '../services/recipi.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  //  jsons:any;


  constructor(private recipiservice:RecipiService ){
    this.recipiservice.getData();
  }
}
```

**details.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { RecipiService } from '../services/recipi.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.page.scss'],
})
export class DetailsPage implements OnInit {
  information = null ;

  constructor(private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute,private recipiservice:RecipiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.recipiservice.getDetails(id).subscribe(result =>{
      console.log('details', result)
      this.information = result;
    });
  }

}
```

**recipi.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RecipiService {
  jsons: any;
  url = '/assets/resource.json';


    //json:any;
   constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

  getData(){

    let data: Observable<any> = this.http.get(this.url);
    data.subscribe(results =>{
      // console.log(this.jsons);
        return this.jsons = results;
    })
}

getDetails(id){
   //console.log(id);
   return this.http.get(this.url); //how to get single item with id & this line code not complate . please help me for complate my code 
}
}
```

> here all item get . but i went get to singel item

[image: here all item get . but i went get to singel item]

> Like it, get single item with id

[image: Like it, get single item with id]

this is ionic 4 app.this is ionic 4 app.this is ionic 4 app.this is ionic 4 app.this is ionic 4 app.this is ionic 4 app.this is ionic 4 app.

Comment: Your question is not really clear, can you please add details about what is expected, what goes wrong in your code, if you have errors, etc. By the way using `/assets/resource.json?1` will not return the element with id `1` but the whole JSON (unless it's served dynamically by a script we don't see here). What goes after the `?` will simply be ignored

Comment: how to get single element with id  from /assets/resource.json

Comment: now my  question is really clear .I hope I can benefit you

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do it just using the URL, either you load the whole JSON and extract the part with good id in JS, or you need to create an endpoint script that serves a part of the JSON file depending of the URL parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following in your service's code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'; // make sure to import the map operator


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RecipiService {
  jsons: any;
  url = '/assets/resource.json';


  //json:any;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

  getData(){

    let data: Observable<any> = this.http.get(this.url);
    data.subscribe(results =>{
      // console.log(this.jsons);
        return this.jsons = results;
    })
  }

  getDetails(id){
    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .pipe(map(response) => {
        return response.find((item) => (item.id === id));
      })
  }
```

}

Since I'm using a `===` for comparison, please make sure the `id` that you pass into `getDetails` and the `id` property from the server response within each item have same data types. I.e. both should be number, or both should be string values.

[**Stackblitz Working Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phrkkt)

Hope this helps.

Comment: many error show . Clicking on the link will see ,error show picture  http://prntscr.com/n2p4y2

Comment: @user7379812 are you sure you've imported the `map` operator as I've mentioned on my answer?
I also attached a working Stackblitz example in my answer now. Please check.

Comment: @user7379812 that is almost what I suggested :) Please accept the answer if it helped you.